# Is the direction of rotation vector a convention?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, vectors, conventions, angular-velocity

Rotation vector is along the axis of rotation and is given by right hand rule. As much I understand, rotation can be clockwise as well as anticlockwise, in other words it has direction. So it can(or should?) be represented by a vector. Direction of rotation vector is given by right hand rule. Is this just some sort of convention or is there any scientific reason for this? Why not left hand  or any other rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a convention. We have to pick a positive and a negative side, so we picked the right hand rule.

This is just like we picked that the Z axis points in such a way that when facing X-Y from the usual point of view, Z grows positive "away from the paper".

(Notice that I didn't mention the choice of X or Y axis in the same way. We arbitrarily choose which way we *draw* the X and Y axis, but we don't choose which way they "*go*" the way we choose the way the Z axis "goes". It's not hard to see that you can draw the X and Y axis in any direction of your choice by simply changing the observer's vantage point and angle, without changing anything else. E.g. by "looking from behind" or "Upside-down". However the Z axis has to be "picked arbitrarily", because you can't flip it just by changing your vantage point. You would be forced to apply a reflection.)

Notice also that there are only two choices for the rule: right-hand rule or left-hand-rule. the choice has to be consistent, and you can only choose which way the arrow goes: "that way", or "the opposite way". There is no "any other rule" available.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer is originally from Quora.](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-right-hand-thumb-rule-a-convention/answer/Brian-Bi?srid=pT3A)

> It is in fact a convention, and it can be avoided by using the correct
>   algebraic objects.
>
> If a wheel is spinning clockwise, whether you choose to represent its
>   angular momentum as pointing away from you (right-hand rule) or toward
>   you (left-hand rule) doesn't change the reality of how it's actually
>   rotating, which is clockwise. In other words, quantities whose
>   direction depend on the arbitrary choice of right-hand or left-hand
>   rule simply are not observable at all. Observable quantities are
>   always independent of handedness convention.
>
> A good example comes from electromagnetism. To assign a direction to
>   the magnetic field around a current-carrying wire, you need the
>   right-hand rule. And in order to determine the force on a parallel
>   current-carrying wire due to this field, you need to apply the
>   right-hand rule again. But if all you do is observe the force, and
>   ignore the magnetic field for a moment, the result you'll observe is
>   independent of handedness: if the current travels in the same
>   direction in the two wires then they are attracted, and if it travels
>   in opposite directions then they are repelled. This, you can observe
>   directly; the magnetic field, you cannot.

More reading:
[Brian Bi's answer to What is a pseudovector?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-pseudovector/answer/Brian-Bi)